# I have got an array of pixels(having x and y values). how to set color of pixel points to red

Tags: image-processing, cocos2d-iphone, pixel, cocos2d-x

I just want to know
how to set a particular pixel's colour to red?
suppose x =37 y=54 and i want to change this pixel's colour to red.
I have no clue how to do it.
I have got the values of points around a particular object into an array of pixels using marching square algo.

Comment: Set what pixel?  A pixel in a `CCSprite`?  A pixel in a `UIImage`?  A pixel in a `CGImage`?  A pixel in a `UIView`?  What if you're on a Retina display - do you really want to set just one tiny Retina pixel, or do you want to set a 1-point by 1-point square (which is a 2x2 square of pixels)?

Comment: m working with CCSprite. CGImage is also fine to work with. not retina display. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the pixels of an existing `CGImage`.  You have to create a new `CGImage` with the pixel changed.  These are the steps:

1. [Create a `CGBitmapContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) with `CGBitmapContextCreate`.
2. [Draw the existing `CGImage` into it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) using `CGContextDrawImage`.
3. Draw the pixel using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` and `CGContextFillRect`.
4. Create a new `CGImage` using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.

Instead of using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` and `CGContextFillRect`, you could tweak the bitmap data directly after retrieving a pointer to it with `CGBitmapContextGetData`.  That would be faster if you're going to do it a lot.

Also, if you're going to do it a lot, you will want to create the bitmap context and draw the original image into it just once, and keep the bitmap context around for diddling.  But creating the new `CGImage` from the bitmap context may be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but here's a general answer:

Pixel colours are usually represented with 3 or 4 bytes:

Red - Green - Blue - ( Alpha )

There should be a function available in the SDK you are using that enables you set these values for a pixel. You would set red to 255 and the others to 0 if you want a pure red colour.

Comment: m working with CCSprite. CGImage is also fine to work with. not retina display. thnx –

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with CCSprite, just change the color using the `color` property of the sprite:

`mySprite.color=ccc3(123,234,12); //use whatever color values for red, green, blue you want`

max values for red, green, blue in `ccc3` are 255; when maxed out, the color is the natural color of the sprite; you cannot go brighter, but changing these values will move to other colors or darken the image if all are changed by same amount down.

for pure red, use `ccc3(255,0,0)`